# Need advice on tapping into touch screen connected to LCD

Tags: touchscreen, touch-panel, touch

I'm hoping to get some advice on a technical issue I'm currently facing. I am attempting to tap into a touch screen that is connected to an LCD, but I'm feeling a bit confused about how to proceed. Essentially, I want to use the LCD's original touch screen input for my own computer and display.

I've considered two methods for achieving this, but both have their potential drawbacks. The first method involves using a splitter to clone the signal and feed it to both the original LCD and my computer simultaneously. However, I'm worried that this won't work because it's not possible to split a resistance signal in this way.

The second method I've considered is connecting the original wire to a splitter and using relays to control the signal. When the relay is active, it will transmit the signal to my computer, but when it's deactivated, the signal will be left for the original LCD.

My main concerns are whether it's possible to simply split and duplicate a resistive touch screen signal, given that it involves resistance, and where I can find the necessary parts for this project. I've had a difficult time finding parts so far, as the resistance display is connected with an FFC 4 pin 0.5 mm pitch ribbon cable, and I can't seem to locate similar wires or connectors.

I've attached some images for reference below. Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5EZQ.jpg)

Comment: Welcome Jonas.  Please include your linked images in your post (instead of just the link), as links often change, or go dead.  This will ensure the usefulness of your post into the future. (In addition, you will get more responses if you include the actual pictures.).

Comment: the touch panel and the LCD panel are usually two separate devices